# How to use different Django Rest Framework serializers for the same request in Generic Views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework in an API project and am trying to figure out if there's a way to use two different serializers with the generic views (e.g. CreateAPIView). I want to use one serializer for deserializing a POST request, and a different one for serializing the resulting response.

Here's what I'm trying to do; I'll illustrate using the Album/Track examples from the docs:

The model that I'm working with has a ForeignKey relationship. In the API, I'd like to just be able to include the FK in the request when assigning the relationship, so in the serializer I'm using a PrimaryKeyRelatedField, similar to how the AlbumSerializer handles the relationship to Tracks:

```
class CreateAlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

However, on the response, I'd like to include a full representation of the Album using a ModelSerializer, not just the PK, slug, etc., something like this:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')
```

The generic DRF views allow you to either specify the `serializer_class` or override the `get_serializer_class` method, but I can't figure out how to use that to accomplish what I'm after.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? This seems like a reasonable thing to want to do, but I can't seem to grok how to get it done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Approach #1

Overwrite the generic mixins in the DRF `ViewSet`. For example:

```
class MyViewSet(CreateModelMixin, MultipleSerializersViewMixin, ViewSet):
    serializer_class = CreateAlbumSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        saved = self.perform_create(serializer)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=saved, serializer_class=AlbumSerializer)

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save()
```

`MultipleSerializersViewMixin` is taken from [`django-rest-framework-braces`](https://github.com/dealertrack/django-rest-framework-braces).

### Approach #2

Customize `to_representation` of the `CreateAlbumSerializer`. For example:

```
class MyViewSet(CreateModelMixin, ViewSet):
    serializer_class = CreateAlbumSerializer

class CreateAlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(CreateAlbumSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data['tracks'] = TrackSerializer(instance=instance.tracks).data
        return data
```

### Comparison

I personally like approach #1 instead of #2 even though it is more verbose since it does not leak any of the custom create/response logic to serializers. I think serializer should just know how to serialize and all custom requirements to pick different serializers for the job should be done in the views.